# Python ndarray form big file, memory error

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a problem with numpy:

- I need `numpy` to make my module efficient
- however, loading the file `targets.csv` in a `ndarray` causes a `MemoryError` when the file is too big (more than 150 Mo, and I have 12 Go RAM...)
- Is there any way this could be rewritten to handle a big `targets.csv` file while still have `numpy` amazing speed??

Thanks!

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial
import cv2

"""loading files"""

points = np.array([(int(R), int(G), int(B), float(X), float(Y), float(Z))
              for R, G, B, X, Y, Z in csv.reader(open('colorlist.csv'))])
    # load X,Y,Z coordinates of 'points' in a np.array 
print "colorlist loaded"

targets = np.array([(float(X), float(Y), float(Z))
           for X, Y, Z in csv.reader(open('targets.csv'))])
    # load the XYZ target values in a np.array
print "targets loaded"

img = cv2.imread("MAP.tif", -1)
height, width = img.shape
total = height * width
# load dimensions of tif image
print "MAP loaded"


"""doing geometry"""

tri = scipy.spatial.Delaunay(points[:,[3,4,5]], furthest_site=False) # True makes an almost BW picture
# Delaunay triangulation

indices = tri.simplices
# indices of vertices

vertices = points[indices]
# the vertices for each tetrahedron

tet = tri.find_simplex(targets)
# find which tetrahedron each target belongs to

U = tri.transform[tet,:3]
V = targets - tri.transform[tet,3]  
b = np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', U, V)
bcoords = np.c_[b, 1 - b.sum(axis=1)]
# find the barycentric coordinates of each point
```

Comment: I'm assuming that "Mo" is [Mb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte) and "Go" is [Gb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte). If that's true you should have no trouble reading a 150Mb file into memory with 12Gb of RAM. You might want to edit your question with the exact error, including the [stack trackback](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#exceptions), so we can help you figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried memory-map yet? It can be called via [numpy.memmap](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) . That is designed for files that are too large to load into ram.

Here is the description I copied from the docstring:

> Create a memory-map to an array stored in a
> binary file on disk.
>
> Memory-mapped files are used for accessing small segments of large
> files on disk, without reading the entire file into memory. Numpy’s
> memmap’s are array-like objects. This differs from Python’s mmap
> module, which uses file-like objects.
>
> This subclass of ndarray has some unpleasant interactions with some
> operations, because it doesn’t quite fit properly as a subclass. An
> alternative to using this subclass is to create the mmap object
> yourself, then create an ndarray with ndarray.**new** directly,
> passing the object created in its ‘buffer=’ parameter.
>
> This class may at some point be turned into a factory function which
> returns a view into an mmap buffer.

And it is fairly simple to use. You can refer to the doc for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that only by using the x64 version of Python 2.7, scipy, openCV and numpy, it works very well